# Debugging an Elixir Application

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, pry

I come from a Ruby on Rails background. So, Binding.pry is my very best friend. I just started picking up Elixir and I'm really enjoying it, but I'm curious what the best debugging techniques are? Basically, what is the counterpart of [pry](/questions/tagged/pry) for Elixir? Also, is the debugging paradigm different because it's functional?

Comment: You know the blog post which @simone linked below is the very first link that comes up when I google "Debugging Elixir".  Just trying to teach a developer how to fish . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing to `pry` is [`IEx.pry`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html#pry/1).

You can start your Elixir/Phoenix application like this:

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

Or, if you don't use Phoenix:

```
iex -S mix
```

This will spawn a REPL that works similarly to Ruby's `irb`, where you can pretty much debug anything you want.

[This comprehensive article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/04/debugging-techniques-in-elixir-lang/) by the authors of Elixir explains how to use `IEx.pry` and other debugging techniques, you may want to have a read.